# Find lowercase character in uppercase word

Tags: awk, regular-expression, text-formatting

I'm trying to change formatting for few specific characters that appear in lowercase, while the whole word is formatted uppercase.

file looks like:

```
„АРХЕОЛОшКИ ПРЕГЛЕД (АРХЕОЛОшКИ ПРЕГЛЕД)“ - годишен информатор на Археолошкото друштво на Југославија, односно на Сојузот на археолошките друштва на Југославија. Содржи прелиминарни соопштенија од археолошки истражувања вршени на територијата на некогашна СФРЈ, подредени според
```

using simple regex and notepad when i tried to use regex А-Ш always selects      two characters insead only ш ?
any help ?

thanks

Comment: Could you post output of the command: `file name_of_your_file`

Answer (score 0):

Try the following to get lowercase charecters in uppercase word:

```
 cat file | tr ' ' '\n' | grep -o '[[:upper:]].*[[:upper:]]' | grep -o '[[:lower:]]'
```

- we can use `tr` to split each word in a separate line.
- `grep -o '[[:upper:]].*[[:upper:]]''` which will grep the word which all starts and ends with upper case.
- `grep -o '[[:lower:]]'` which will grep only lower case.

Output which i got from your context

```
ш
ш
```

Answer (score 0):

With GNU `sed`

```
sed 's/[[:alpha:]]*[[:upper:]][[:alpha:]]*[[:upper:]][[:alpha:]]*/\U&/g'
```

Would turn to upper case all the sequences of letters that contain at least two uppercase ones.

So would change `АРХЕОЛОшКИ` to `АРХЕОЛОШКИ`, but leave `Југославија` as is.

Comment: i tried this way , but it doesn't  do any change to the file 
sed -i 's/[[:alpha:]]*[[:upper:]][[:alpha:]]*[[:upper:]][[:alpha:]]*/\U&/g' test.txt

Comment: @SeeInside360 Your problem looks like file encoding problem, not a regex. Try to answer my question under OP and post output of the command: `file test.txt`